# swift How to add view into layer correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, calayer

I have a Gauge view. Here minimized code:

```swift
class GaugeView: UIView {
    // MARK: PROPERTIES

    private let labelFactory = LabelFactory()
    
    /// Minimum value.
    var minValue: Double = 0
    /// Maximum value.
    var maxValue: Double = 100
    
    /// The thickness of the ring.
    private var ringThickness: CGFloat = 30
    
    private var startAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 3/4 + .pi/20
    private var endAngle: CGFloat = .pi/4 + .pi * 2
    private let points = 24
    
    private lazy var ellipseLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.butt
        layer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.bevel
        layer.strokeEnd = 0
        return layer
    }()
    
    // MARK: DRAWING
    
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        addLayer(ellipseLayer)
        drawBorderedLayer(&ellipseLayer)
        
        let subView = buildCircleView(text: "1", size: 50)
        addSubview(subView)
        subView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.size.equalTo(50)
        }
    }
    
    private func drawBorderedLayer(_ subLayer: inout CAShapeLayer) {
        let thickness: CGFloat = 30
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height / 2)
        let radius: CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2 + 40
        
        subLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat((30 - minValue)/(maxValue - minValue))
        subLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        subLayer.frame = CGRect(x: center.x - radius - thickness / 2,
                                y: center.y - radius - thickness / 2,
                                width: (radius + thickness / 2 ) * 2,
                                height: (radius + thickness / 2) * 2)
        subLayer.bounds = subLayer.frame
        let smoothedPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: subLayer.position,
                                        radius: radius,
                                        startAngle: startAngle,
                                        endAngle: endAngle,
                                        clockwise: true)
        subLayer.path = smoothedPath.cgPath
        subLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(thickness)
    }
    
    private func addLayer(_ subLayer: CAShapeLayer) {
        if subLayer.superlayer == nil {
            layer.addSublayer(subLayer)
        }
    }
    
    private func addView(_ subView: UIView) {
        if subView.superview == nil {
            addSubview(subView)
        }
    }
    
    private func buildCircleView(
        text: String,
        size: CGFloat) -> UIView {
        let containerView = UIView()
        let circleView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
        circleView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        circleView.backgroundColor = Color.grayBackground
        
        let label = labelFactory.make(withStyle: .headingH2,
                                      text: text,
                                      textColor: .white,
                                      textAlignment: .center)
        circleView.addSubview(label)
        label.snp.makeConstraints { $0.center.equalToSuperview() }
        
        containerView.addSubview(circleView)
        return containerView
    }
}
```

Image:

[image]

And I want to add circle view into the ellipse layer:

```
...
let subView = buildCircleView(text: "1", size: 50)
ellipseLayer.addSublayer(subView.layer)
subView.snp.makeConstraints {
  $0.size.equalTo(50)
}
...
```

On screen displays just result:

[image]

How to add circle view correct way into ellipse. Like here:

[image]

Here my view controller:

```
class ViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black

    private let gaugeView = GaugeView()
    gaugeView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    gaugeView.setNeedsDisplay()

    [gaugeView].forEach(view.addSubview(_:))
    gaugeView.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.size.equalTo(300)
      $0.center.equalToSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would u add a view to layer? Why cant u draw with `uibezierpath` a small circle u need ahead of arc?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I didn't try this way :))